# Unexpected results when looping through the return value of cursor

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I have a cursor that returns a summed double equivalane to `SELECT SUM(balance) FROM accounts WHERE accountName="accountY" OR description="descriptionX"` in the following way:

```
public Double itemSum(String[] sumCriteria) {
    Cursor cursor = mainAccountsDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(balance) FROM accounts WHERE ?=? OR description=?",
            new String[]{sumCriteria[0], sumCriteria[1], sumCriteria[2]});

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor.getDouble(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In my Java code I have the following:

```
public void dbGenerator(AccountAdapterView adapter, String filter1, String filter2, String filter3) {
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    for (int i = 0; i < listFromDB.size(); i++) {
        ListParser newAccount;
        String accountNameDisplay = listFromDB.get(i).getaccountName();
        String descriptionDisplay = listFromDB.get(i).getDescription();
        Double balanceCompare = maSource.itemSum(new String[]{"accountName",accountNameDisplay,accountNameDisplay, "null"});
        Double balance = listFromDB.get(i).getBalance();
        String formatted = formatter.format(balance);
        newAccount = new ListParser(accountNameDisplay, descriptionDisplay, formatted);
        adapter.add(newAccount);
    }
}
```

where `listFromDB` is a pre-populated `ListArray` containing the names of the accounts from the `"accountName"` column of the DB.

Checking `logcat` the first output of the 10 sample rows results in an unsummed value of where the first populated list item matches `"description"` column and the following 9 sums are 0.

If I execute the SQL to each one of the 10 rows I get the correct sum. Why is the cursor providing a different output?

Here is a small representation of what the data looks like.

```
accountName,description,balance
account1,description1,500
account2,description2,20
account3,description3,-68
account4,account1,-1000
account5,description4,400
account6,account2,180
```

Comment: "Checking logcat the first output of the 10 sample rows results in an unsummed value of where the first populated list item matches "description" column and the following 9 sums are 0." — you might want to expand on this. Its hard to see your problem especially since you didn't also provide `getBalance`

Comment: Regarding the quoted text, in my sample data has `account1` as the first accountName. The second column has `account4` as accountName and `account1` as the description. I would get that -1000 for my first sum then 0 for rest. As for getBalance is just a getter that obtains the balance from the ListArray `listFromDB` nothing special about it. I have also outputted the `accountName` and `description`that are being sent to `itemSum` and that's all in order.

Answer (score 0):

The summation in the *`itemSum`* looks correct to me.

What you probably need to post into logcat in order to see each sum value is this line

```
  Double balanceCompare = maSource.itemSum(new String[]
 {"accountName",accountNameDisplay,accountNameDisplay, "null"});
```

inside the loop itself.

Now, why are you doing

```
Double balanceCompare = maSource.itemSum(new String[]{"accountName",accountNameDisplay,accountNameDisplay, "null"});
newAccount = new ListParser(accountNameDisplay, descriptionDisplay, formatted);
        adapter.add(newAccount);
```

If the `balanceCompare`itself is not invoked (not filled) into the `ListParser`. I mean the `ListParser's` constructor is accepting `accountNameDisplay, descriptionDisplay, formatted`, where is the `balanceCompare` then?

Perhaps you mean (instead)

```
// balanceCompare ?
String formatted = formatter.format(balanceCompare );
        newAccount = new ListParser(accountNameDisplay, descriptionDisplay, formatted);
```

Also, If recall, *placeholder* only relevant when applied to some values, so the first `?` for the `WHERE ?=?` couldn't be bound.

Comment: I entered that exact thing into logcat which is how I saw the values being what they are. `balanceCompare` was added as a recent thing to get the sum, ultimately it would be incorporated exactly how you show it. At first I was outputting the account and start balance. Now I'm summing all transactions that occur within those which is where itemSum comes into place. I just can't output the correct sum for some reason even though the correct information, outputted to my logcat as well, is being sent to itemSum

Comment: Here's the thing that is confusing me, what if your `accountName` in the db *doesn't match* but it matches the `description ` instead? Take for example the 4th row in your sample, you pass `account1` into the function, then the `account1` doesn't match the 4th row of your sample but as you use `OR description` thus the 4th will also be taken. Why would the `description` contains one of its counterparts' account names by the way?